# Make a page background transparent

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to make a certain page to be transparent. I tried setting the backgroundDesign to transparent but it doesn't work for me.

Here is the part of my code:

```
var page = this.getView().byId("idPage");
page.setBackgroundDesign("Transparent");
```

Is there a way to make a page transparent?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does not "it doesn't work for me" mean? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is working. However, the app in which your page is added, also defines the background-color and background-image ( default in CSS class).

CSS class: `.sapUiGlobalBackgroundColor, .sapMGlobalBackgroundColor`.

[image]
I don't know how you want your view to appear. You might play with above classes to suit your requirements.

EDIT: You can set the background image and background color of the app.

Check link: [sap.m.App](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.App.html#constructor)